# NHibernate - Retrieving Lots of Data Becomes Exponentially Slow

Tags: nhibernate

I have an issue when I retrieve lots of data in NHibernate (such as when producing a report) the page becomes exponentially slower the more data it has to retrieve.   I found the following article:

http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2008/10/30/bulk-data-operations-with-nhibernate-s-stateless-sessions.aspx

It explains how doing bulk data operations in NHibernate is slow since the first level cache grows too large and how you should use the IStatelessSession instead.  The trouble I have is that I don't wish to tie my application to NHibernate so I've added a wrapper around ISession.  I then use Linq as my query mechanism but IStatelessSession does not support Linq (it may do in NHibernate 3 but the Linq provider is not stable as it stands at the moment).

I then read that you could do a clear after so many iterations to clear out the first level cache.  The problem now is that you can't use lazy loading.  The linq provider doesn't allow you to override the mapping defined (or eagerly fetch the additional data) so whenever I grab data which is lazy loaded after I have cleared the session an exception is thrown.

I'm completely lost on what do now.  I like the ease of producing reports with linq but the limitations of the inbuilt linq provider in NHibernate seem to be holding me back.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could show me an alternative approach.  Thanks

Comment: What do you mean retrieving lots of data? Are you talking about 10 rows with some relational data or 1000s or rows? If you're retrieving > 100 rows I would say you're doing it wrong. Can you explain your scenario (not your problem) cos it might just be your scenario thats wrong.

Comment: Hi Phil, we're talking potentially 1000's of rows.  It's a one off report so i don't mind it taking a few minutes but currently if i take 100 records it takes 5 minutes, 20 records takes 15 minutes and 30 records takes over an hour.  You'll notice the exponetial increase which i'm trying to get to the bottom of.

Comment: So the issue isn't actually retrieving the records and displaying them, it's processing the records? How much is done in the database and how much is done in code? Can you pre-calculate the data in advance so when the report is generated it's not doing so much processing, mainly just retrieving. Also if you have joins/where criteria, have you profiled the query to see where it's slow.

Comment: It's hard to answer this question without knowing your classes, mapping, and LINQ query. Are you sure you're not hitting a SELECT N+1 issue as that will often lead to exponential slowdowns with an increasing number of records. A suitably placed join or mapping modification usually fixes the issue. So more info would be appreciated.

Comment: Cheers everyone.  See my response to the marked answer for further information on how i tackled lazy loading and the select n + 1 issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that this isn't supported by ICriteria or Linq methods; however, you could consider using hql named queries for this. Setting the `"read-only"` attribute on the mapping will prevent the entities from being tracked in the session. Further information can be found [here](http://darioquintana.com.ar/blogging/2007/10/16/why-use-named-queries-with-nhibernate/).

As this pertains to your usage, I wouldn't worry about not being able to do everything in the context of linq-to-nhibernate. Although it's great for handling most scenarios, specialized usages like reporting are often better left to methods such as hql or even native sql. Don't be afraid to have a few `.GetEntitySummaryReport()` methods on your repositories, it's not the end of the world.

**Update**:

If adding methods to your repository feels *wrong*, I'd suggest having a look at using an [Enhanced Query Object](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/enhanced-query-object.html) which provides a great way to encapsulate a specialized query in a provider-agnositc fashion.

Comment: Hi Dan, cheers for your suggestions.  The extra methods against the repository is one idea but it does mean i'll have to do some extra work if i ever plan on upgrading my application to the entity framework.  Ideally i'd like to work in Linq.

Comment: I ended up adding the additional methods to my repository.  I guess i'll just have a little bit of work to do if i ever plan on upgrading.  One option i did play around with was using Expand to eagerly load the data which allowed me to clear the session.  This is ok but for ideal performance your suggestion works.